# Understanding $d/d{\ln}x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function in the form of $$\phi \equiv \frac{d\Omega}{dx}x$$

My aim is to turn $d/dx$ into $d/d{\ln}x$

So I have written

$$\frac{d\Omega}{dx} = \frac{d\Omega}{d{\ln}x}\frac{d{\ln}x}{dx}$$
so
$$\frac{d\Omega}{dx} = \frac{d\Omega}{d{\ln}x}\frac{1}{x}$$

Thus $$\phi_1 \equiv \frac{d\Omega}{d{\ln}x}$$

but in my notes it's written as $$\phi_2 \equiv \frac{d\Omega - 1}{d{\ln}x}$$

which of these relations correct $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ ? Or they are the same maybe ...?

From another post in here it seems I should get some $-1$. But I cannot see how..

[Question on $\frac{d}{d \ln{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97851/question-on-fracdd-lnx)

So simply what is $\phi$ in terms of $d/d{\ln}x$ ?

Comment: The circle in the post means you need to multiply first, then take the derivative. You take the derivative first, then you multiply.. So you are doing $$\left(\frac{d\Omega}{dx}\right)x$$instead of $$\frac d{dx}(\Omega x)$$If you use the product rule on the last equation you get $$\left(\frac{d\Omega}{dx}\right)x+\Omega$$

Comment: I can't comment on notes you haven't shown, but let's first be clear about what's going on in the linked question. $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\circ x-1\right)$ is the operator sending $f$ to$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\circ x-1\right)f=\frac{d}{dx}(xf)-1f=x\frac{d}{dx}f.$$

Comment: [This operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) is usually denoted more concisely as either $x\frac{d}{dx}$, $\frac{d}{d\ln x}$ or $\frac{d}{d\log x}$. (I had to put this in another comment because, due to some bug I don't understand, the hyperlink wouldn't render properly after the display-line equation.)

Comment: So $$\frac{d\Omega}{dx} = \frac{d\Omega}{d{\ln}x}\frac{d{\ln}x}{dx}$$ is correct ?